# Can not resolve JavaParser

Tags: antlr

JavaParser.CallContext and JavaParser.FunctionDeclContext do not seem to be able to resolve. This is modeled after page 139 in the definitive antlr reference.
Am I missing a Lib?

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.MultiMap;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.OrderedHashSet;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeWalker;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;
import org.stringtemplate.v4.ST;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Set;



 static class FunctionListener extends JavaBaseListener {
            Graph graph = new Graph();
            String currentFunctionName = null;

            public void enterFunctionDecl(JavaParser.FunctionDeclContext ctx) {
                currentFunctionName = ctx.ID().getText();
                graph.nodes.add(currentFunctionName);
            }

            public void exitCall(JavaParser.CallContext ctx) {
                String funcName = ctx.ID().getText();
                // map current function to the callee
                graph.edge(currentFunctionName, funcName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you generate Java classes from the Java.g4 grammar file? If so, these could not be found in your CLASSPATH. And if you do not have a Java.g4 grammar file, you should go back a couple of pages because you missed some crucial instructions.

Comment: Which files do you have, what's in them and what did you do with them? Like, do you have a `Java.g4`? Does it contain definitions for `Call` and `FunctionDecl`? Did you run the grammar through ANTLR and compile the resulting Java files? Are the resulting class files in your class path? Alternatively: what are your build steps / what build system are you using? And what is the exact wording of the error message you get? Does it fail to resolve `JavaParser` or only `JavaParser.FunctionDeclContext` etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have seen this one, and I dont have enough points to "comment",  but let me ask a question first; It looks like you are trying to produce an external version of the AST on page 137, You took the examples and renamed them to the grammar you had generated already. I'm going to assume that the rest of it is working or you would have had a lot more errors than this one ! Is that the goal ? Are you after just the calling methods/classes or are you after the full homogeneous AST ?

This depends on the grammar entry points. That's not as obvious in the book as it seems. You referenced functionDecl, which looks to be an entry in the Cymbol.g4, but doesn't exist in Java.g4 So rather than JavaParser.FunctionDeclContext I suggest JavaParser.classOrInterfaceDeclarationContext. It should should pull up the right method. I will also confess that I don't know what the exitCall would map to. I could use the illumination on that myself.

Were you after the whole AST or only the call graph ? If the whole AST, I think you can use enterEveryRule or ExitEveryRule for that as well, but confirmation would be good.

So start by regenerating your grammar, change your program to reference the rule entry point in the .g4 files, then see if it all works.

Thanks

Comment: YES ! Thats exactly what I am after. An AST but in text so I can feed it to the graphics processor. I successfully switched to the classOrInterfaceDeclaration and it works. exitCall resolved also. So all good except one question. Should I have grabbed compileunit to get the whole tree ? Or would ExitEveryRule be the right place ?